# rmic code duplicate classes intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, rad, ejb-2.x

Trying to convert a project from RAD into intelliJ.   The project contains a several ejb2 modeules and ejb client modules.  The client modules contain  There are a lot of modules that depend on each other and a lot of code that has been generated by the rmic compilier.

Most of the code is in the org.omg.stug.javax.ejb package.  Is there anyway to tell intellij to ingore the duplicate classes?

Comment: Port the whole project to maven. It'll save you a lot of time and heartache in the long run.

Comment: I would love to use Maven.  Project is rather large with 50+ modules

Comment: That's pushing toward 'must' use maven. The bigger the problem, the more pressing it is that you use maven. Otherwise, you'll probably not succeed.